# Rxjs 5 - Simple Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to get the value from a simple ajax request, but I don't understand how to do that. Here is the code:

```
Rx.Observable
  .ajax({ url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' })
  .subscribe(function(data) { return data.response; });
```

I searched everywhere and there is no simple explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Observable.ajax` can accept `string` or `Object` with the following interface:

> ```
> interface AjaxRequest {
>   url?: string; // URL of the request
>   body?: any;  // The body of the request
>   user?: string; 
>   async?: boolean; // Whether the request is async
>   method?: string; // Method of the request, such as GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
>   headers?: Object; // Optional headers
>   timeout?: number;
>   password?: string;
>   hasContent?: boolean;
>   crossDomain?: boolean; //true if a cross domain request, else false
>   withCredentials?: boolean;
>   createXHR?: () => XMLHttpRequest; //a function to override if you need to use an alternate XMLHttpRequest implementation
>   progressSubscriber?: Subscriber<any>;
>   responseType?: string;
> }
> ```
>
> see [AjaxObservable.ts on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts)

And here is examples:

```js
const { Observable, combineLatest } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { ajax } = rxjs.ajax; // = require("rxjs/ajax")
const { map } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

// simple GET request example
const simple$ = ajax('https://httpbin.org/get');

// POST request example
const complex$ = ajax({
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-rxjs-is': 'Awesome!'
  },
  body: {
    hello: 'World!',
  }
});

const htmlSubscription = combineLatest(simple$, complex$)
  .subscribe(([simple, complex]) => {
    const simpleResponse = JSON.stringify(simple.response, null, 2);
    const complexResponse = JSON.stringify(complex.response, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <span><b>GET</b> https://httpbin.org/get</span>
        <pre>${simpleResponse}</pre>

        <span><b>POST</b> https://httpbin.org/post</span>
        <pre>${complexResponse}</pre>
      </div>`;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">loading ...</div>
```

Comment: Yup I know you can map it or console.log it to view the response. Sorry I didn't explained my question well. Let's say you store that in a variable. Is there a way to call it and get the value back?

Comment: I've corrected my answer, now I'm using it "as a variable".
If you wondering how to use Observables with your javascript code - take a look at examples in the documentation https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/examples/autocomplete

Comment: Or take a look at this gist/course - https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: Quick question does anyone know if RxJS can make Ajax calls then why does angular have its own http lib?

Comment: Ray Fan: because they're separate libraries.  You can use RxJS without Angular.  The reverse is not completely true as Angular uses Rx internally, but if you wanted to use the Rx AJAX capabilities instead of the Angular HTTP service, there's nothing stopping you from doing so...

Answer (score 6):

Typescript version

```
"dependencies": { 
     "rxjs": "^5.1.0"
 }
```

and

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';


 const posts$ = Observable
  .ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .map(e => e.response);


  const htmlSubscription = posts$
  .subscribe(res => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use switchMap ..

```
const response$ = request$.switchMap((url) => {
  console.log(url);
  return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
});
```

switchMap flattens a stream of streams and converts it to a stream that just emits the inner streams responses. If a second innerStream is emitted, the first stream is killed and the second one proceeds on its own.

See this bin which demos streamed requests over HTTP .. https://jsbin.com/duvetu/32/edit?html,js,console,output