# Is there any RxJS based http request library?

Tags: ajax, request, rxjs

I am looking for a HTTP request library which is RxJS based. Just a tool Angular 4.3+ HTTPClient.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

I want to use a RxJS based http client, not in an Angular Project. It's better to have Interceptors feature and based on fetch API(not xhr).

I have look at [rx-http-request](https://github.com/njl07/rx-http-request), but it seems not too much people use it.

Comment: You can use `Rx.Observable.ajax`. As an example see [RxJS 5 simple ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286476/rxjs-5-simple-ajax-request/41288856#41288856)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic since it asks for recommendations about software libraries.