# How to get header properties from backend api using rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, angular7, angular-httpclient

I am getting a file stream from backend. the header keeps the name of the file with extension. But how to get those property in fronent end. here is my code,not getting the value as well no error.

```
downloadFile(id:number):Observable<any> {

        const options = { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }

        return this.http.get<any>(environment.baseUrl+`CourseFileUpload/${id}`, options)
        .pipe(
            map((file) => {
                console.log('header', file.headers('Content-Disposition')); //not getting header value...!?
                return new Blob([file], {type: "application/octet-stream"})
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
    }
```

any one help me?

**I tried with suggestion like :**

```
downloadFile(id:number):Observable<any> {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ observe: 'response'});
        const options = { responseType: 'blob' as 'json', headers:headers  }

        return this.http.get<any>(environment.baseUrl+`CourseFileUpload/${id}`,  options )
        .pipe(
            map(resp => {
                if(resp.headers){
                    const keys = resp.headers.keys();
                    console.log('file',  keys); //nothing consoles!?
                }

                return new Blob([resp], {type: "application/octet-stream"})
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
    }
```

got no response. please any one help me to get response header?

Comment: You can access headers in Response object, take a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288856/3772379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) you need to add `observe: 'response'` into the options to have access to the full response object.

Comment: @dudadub - I added my code in question part. still not getting any response headers.. can  you please have a look  on my updated code and suggest me the correct approach?

Comment: what is the type of `this.http` by the way?

Comment: I am getting unknown object from backend. in which i required to fetch my data.